# Rails3 RSpec is wiping wrong database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I am trying to get my hands on Rspec2 with Rails3 (never used rspec before). I have rspec-rails 2.0.0.beta20. After introducing some basic tests into spec/models and running

```
rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb
```

everthing is fine. However if I just run

```
rake spec
```

My development database is beeing wiped out. Even if I specify the environment explicitly

```
RAILS_ENV=test rake spec
```

My development database is beeing wiped to zero.

What I am doing wrong here? It feels like I am missing the concept for now. Anyone got any tips or could point me to some basic tutorial?

Comment: can you show your spec_helper.rb?

Comment: Sure, http://gist.github.com/562337 I also added part of my gemfile.

Comment: My spec_helper is here http://gist.github.com/562539, Its default from rspec:install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stupid case. While moving the app from Rails2 to Rails3 I messed up database.yml, and my test db was set to devel. :)

Answer (score 1):

Set the following sentence at the top of your `spec_helper.rb` file

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
```

This will ensure you use the right environment.

Comment: I wrote in the original file, that I am setting the RAILS_ENV, and it doesn't help. Besides, my spec helper (http://gist.github.com/562539) contains this file.